# Exporting from SQL using POWERSHELL where the output contains NULLS

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I'm using the below POWERSHELL scrip to export the content of a SQL table to a .csv. It has been working well, unfortunately it's failing as the table in question has now had some NULLS added to it.

Is there a way to modify this to allow it to pass NULLS, or is it best to amend the underlying table.

```
$server = "sqlmtest"
$database = "mi_lookups"
$query = "SELECT * FROM [dbo].[SQLMtest-BIS-BUS-BPS_system_agent_lookup]"

$extractFile = @"
G:\system_Lookup_Tables\system_agent_lookup.csv
"@


$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString

$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.Connection = $connection

$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $command
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
$connection.Close()


$DataSet.Tables[0] | Export-Csv $extractFile
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should not have to modify the table itself at all. Modify your `select` statement such that NULLs are not returned, or your `Export-Csv` pipeline such that NULLs do not cause a problem

Comment: Just a workaround, but couldn't you extend your query by giving column names and using ISNULL([column1], '') or ISNULL([column1], 0) according to datatype ?

Comment: Unfortunately the table contains rows where NULLS are present but I still need to export them. @paul - any suggestions on how I can edit the Export-csv to handle NULLS?

Comment: You could try this: http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/powergui/f/4834/t/19571829

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all (@Paul did suggest this in the comments). To resolve the issue I wrapped the items in the original select with an ISNULL().

```
$query = "SELECT [l].client_key, ISNULL([l].client_name) FROM [dbo].[test] AS [l]"
```

Not a particularly elegant solution but it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just a comment regarding your PowerShell syntax: don't make it harder than necessary.

That here-string is pointless, just make a regular string:

```
$extractFile = "G:\system_Lookup_Tables\system_agent_lookup.csv"
```

This

```
$connectionTemplate = "Data Source={0};Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog={1};"
$connectionString = [string]::Format($connectionTemplate, $server, $database)
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
```

can be rewritten like that:

```
$connection = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source=$server;Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=$database;")
```

And this

```
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command.CommandText = $query
$command.Connection = $connection
```

like so:

```
$command = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand($query, $connection)
```

Same thing with the SqlDataAdapter.

Comment: Thanks. I thought this wasn't particularly well written - I'll re-write and try to implement your suggestions.